# Is this a good workout towards abs?

Tags: running, workout-routines

So I have decided that I wanted to workout some more. I am a footballer, so I already have a pretty normal body and a good diet. Anyways, I have been trying to also improve my stamina and trying to work towards getting abs. Right now, I am running 4-6 miles a day with an average pace of 10-11 minutes per mile, in addition to a 10-15 minute cardio HIIT workout and a 10-15 minute ab workout that I have found on youtube and they seem pretty intense. Is my workout ok or should I add some other things to it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cuold you link the video of those abs and HIIT workout routines?

Comment: Are you doing the same thing everyday? If your goal is getting better over time, you need to progressively overload by doing more reps, heavier, faster etc... If the question is if your ab routine if good, can you tell us what it is exactly? But I'm usually of the opinion that a "routine" that you just tack on to the end of a session is usually not the best way to see results.

Comment: Are you looking to train with football in mind specifically? Or just stamina and abs with no specific regard for sport?

Comment: By overloading, does that mean I should run more at a faster pace, and add other aspects to my workout? Also, I am not looking to train towards football.

Comment: My thinking from this is to burn fat from running and cardio HIIT workout, and build strength in abs with ab workouts, adding stamina is also a bonus. Would this be viable?

Comment: @Ambivalence Well yeah, it's viable in the sense that it wont kill you. If this is an increase in the amount of exercise you get currently, then it's going to be an improvement. If you're looking for hypertrophy, you're gonna want to look into a training plan with correct reps and loads etc for your level (can't really suggest anything without your current plan). If you want to get lean (which can give you a six pack without growing your muscles), you're going to have to look closely at your diet (again can't really give you specifics without more info from you).

Answer (score 0):

"To overload" means to gradually make each exercise harder each workout. In weightlifting, this means adding more reps, or weight each session. You can try to beat your running times/cardio times but for obvious reasons you eventually wont be able to beat your own times and you will stop overload naturally, because you can easily add a few lbs to an exercise but if everyone could beat their running times, everyone would eventually be an olympic runner. The cardio will help burn extra calories, although I'd limit HIIT to about 2 or 3 times a week, and same with running. Depending on the ab workout, you can do that 3 times a week. Your ab workout should include a rotation exercise, a lateral exercise, a transverse abdominus exercise and an upper/lower exercise (or both upper and lower).

Without seeing your ab workout, I can only suggest that you do the above core exercises, and start out doing anti-exercises with static movement, then move onto dynamic movement, before hopping into core work. This is just a personal preference and it'll help your athleticism too